# How to use LEFT OUTER JOIN to identify missing products by vendor?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

This query has been fun to figure out but I have come to place where I need some help.

I have several tables and the ultimate question is:

- How many total parts are "missing", by vendor?

and / or

- How many total parts are "missing", by vendor and category?

**Missing:** has not been utilized by the vendor (see query 1).

Note that parts are not attributed to a product or a vendor because both of those could change based on the season and often the parts inspire what the product will actually be.

Very basically, which part each vendor be aware of is the question we are trying to answer on a high level to determine which vendors have the most missing parts in which categories are those parts missing?

Now, I do have the first query I need working great. What it does is tell me the missing parts by category when I specify the specific vendor.

Here is the SQLfiddle for both the create script for the database and the working query:

Query 1:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/088e7/1

And the query:

```
SELECT 
    c.name AS category,
    COUNT(pt.id) AS parts,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN in_stock IS NULL THEN pt.id END) AS missing_parts
FROM 
    season AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ( 

        SELECT 
            s.id AS season_id,
            s.type season_type,
            max(i.in_stock) AS in_stock
        FROM
            inventory AS i
            JOIN season      AS s  ON i.season_id = s.id
            JOIN product     AS p  ON i.product_id = p.id
            JOIN vendor      AS v  ON p.vendor_id = v.id
            JOIN part        AS pt ON s.part_id = pt.id

        WHERE
            v.id = 2
            AND
            s.type = 'Type A'
        GROUP BY
            1,2) AS seas   ON seas.season_id = s.id AND seas.season_type = s.type
            JOIN part      AS pt ON pt.id = s.part_id
            JOIN part_data AS pd ON pt.id = pd.part_id
            JOIN category  AS c  ON pt.category_id = c.id
    WHERE
        s.type = 'Type A'
GROUP BY
    1;
```

The above works like a charm and here are the results:

```
| name      | parts | missing_parts |
|-----------|-------|---------------|
| category3 | 3     | 2             |
| category4 | 2     | 0             |
| category5 | 2     | 2             |
| category6 | 3     | 3             |
```

My problem is when I try to do a similar query using vendor instead of category at the same time removing the vendor filter. In the following SQL fiddle, you can see that because the parts are in fact missing they of course cannot be attributed to a vendor when querying like I am.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/088e7/2

And them Query 2:

```
SELECT 
    seas.vendor AS vendor,
    COUNT(pt.id) AS parts,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN in_stock IS NULL THEN pt.id END) AS missing_parts 
FROM 
    season AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN     
 (SELECT 
            s.id AS season_id,
            v.name AS vendor, 
            s.type season_type,
            max(i.in_stock) AS in_stock
        FROM
            inventory AS i
            JOIN season      AS s  ON i.season_id = s.id
            JOIN product     AS p  ON i.product_id = p.id
            JOIN vendor      AS v  ON p.vendor_id = v.id
            JOIN part        AS pt ON s.part_id = pt.id

        WHERE
            s.type = 'Type A'
        GROUP BY
            1,2          ) AS seas   ON seas.season_id = s.id AND seas.season_type = s.type
            JOIN part      AS pt     ON pt.id = s.part_id
            JOIN part_data AS pd     ON pt.id = pd.part_id
            JOIN category  AS c      ON pt.category_id = c.id

    AND
        s.type = 'Type A'
GROUP BY
    1;
```

The results from query 2:

```
| vendor   | parts | missing_parts |
|----------|-------|---------------|
| (null)   | 4     | 4             |
| Vendor 1 | 2     | 0             |
| Vendor 2 | 3     | 0             |
| Vendor 3 | 2     | 0             |
| Vendor 4 | 2     | 0             |
| Vendor 5 | 2     | 0             |
```

Note the null value which makes sense as those are the "missing" parts I am looking for that cannot be attributed to a Vendor.

What I am wondering is if there is anyway to have the missing part count added to an additional column?

The missing parts column in the desired output is a hard to get accurate because again and thats very point of this query, I don't know...even with this tiny amount of data. Note again, the missing parts do not have vendors but here is my best shot.

```
| vendor   | parts | missing_parts |
|----------|-------|---------------|
| Vendor 1 | 2     | 1             |
| Vendor 2 | 3     | 1             |
| Vendor 3 | 2     | 3             |
| Vendor 4 | 2     | 0             |
| Vendor 5 | 2     | 2             |
```

In an ideal world I would be able to also add category:

```
| category   | vendor   | parts | missing_parts |
|------------|----------|-------|---------------|
| category 1 | Vendor 1 | 2     | 1             |
| category 1 | Vendor 2 | 3     | 1             |
| category 1 | Vendor 3 | 2     | 3             |
| category 1 | Vendor 4 | 2     | 0             |
| category 1 | Vendor 5 | 2     | 2             |
| category 2 | Vendor 1 | 1     | 1             |
| category 2 | Vendor 2 | 1     | 1             |
| category 2 | Vendor 3 | 0     | 3             |
| category 2 | Vendor 4 | 2     | 0             |
| category 2 | Vendor 5 | 0     | 2             |
```

Comment: can you add a sample output showing your desired output

Comment: sqlfiddle is broken (yet again) making a study of this impossible until fixed. attaching data as files would be an alternative/backup. rextester.com or dbfiddle.uk are alternatives to sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF I am understanding what you are looking for, I would first start with what you are ultimately looking for..

A list of distinct parts and categories.  THEN you are looking for who is missing what.  To do so, this is basically a Cartesian of every vendor against this "master list of parts/categories" and who does/not have it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      pt.id, 
      pt.category_id
   from 
      part pt
```

Now, consider the second part.  What are all the possible parts and categories a specific VENDOR has.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      pt.id, 
      pt.category_id, 
      p.vendor_id
   FROM
      season s 
         JOIN inventory i
            ON s.id = i.season_id
            JOIN product p  
               ON i.product_id = p.id
         JOIN part pt 
            ON s.part_id = pt.id
```

In the above tables, I did not need the category or actual vendor tables joined as I only cared about the qualifying IDs of who has what.  First, all possible part ID and category ID, but in the second, we also grab the VENDOR ID who has it.

Now, tie the pieces together starting with the vendor JOINED to category without any "ON" condition.  The join is needed to allow the "v.id" as a lower join in the syntax this will give me a Cartesian of every vendor applied / tested to every category.  Then, the category table joined to all the distinct parts and finally LEFT-JOINED to the distinct parts query PER VENDOR

Finally, add your aggregates and group by.  Due to the left-join, if there IS an VndParts.ID, then the record DOES exist, thus Vendor Parts FOUND count is up.  If the vendor parts id is NULL, then it is missing (hence my sum case/when) for the missing parts count.

```
SELECT
      v.name Vendor,
      c.name  category,
      count( PQParts.ID ) TotalAvailableParts,
      count( VndParts.ID ) VendorParts,
      sum( case when VndParts.ID IS NULL then 1 else 0 end ) MissingParts
   from
      vendor v JOIN
      category c
         JOIN 
         ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                 pt.id, 
                 pt.category_id
              from 
                 part pt ) PQParts
            ON c.id = PQParts.category_id 
            LEFT JOIN
            ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                    pt.id, 
                    pt.category_id, 
                    p.vendor_id
                 FROM
                    season s 
                       JOIN inventory i
                          ON s.id = i.season_id
                          JOIN product p  
                             ON i.product_id = p.id
                       JOIN part pt 
                          ON s.part_id = pt.id ) VndParts
               ON v.id = VndParts.vendor_id
               AND PQParts.ID = VndParts.ID
               AND PQParts.Category_ID = VndParts.Category_ID
   group by
      v.name,
      c.name
```

[Applied against your SQL-Fiddle sample database construct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/088e7/112)

Now, even though you have created sample data of categories 1-6, all of your PARTS are only defined with categories 3-6 as in my sample data result.  I can't force for data that does not exist per the sample query of

```
SELECT
      *
   from
      category c
         JOIN 
         ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                 pt.id, 
                 pt.category_id
              from 
                 part pt ) PQParts
            ON c.id = PQParts.category_id
```

If such actual data DID exist, then those missing pieces of other categories would also be displayed.

Now final note.  You were also looking for a specific SEASON.  I would just add a WHERE clause to accommodate that in the VndParts query.  Then change PQParts query to include the season join such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      pt.id, 
      pt.category_id
   from 
      part pt
```

Now, consider the second part.  What are all the possible parts and categories a specific VENDOR has.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      pt.id, 
      pt.category_id
   FROM
      season s 
         JOIN part pt 
            ON s.part_id = pt.id
   WHERE
      s.type = 'Type A'
```

To further restrict for a specific vendor, add the vendor clause in is easy enough as it is the basis of the of the vendor "v" at the outer criteria, and the vendor reference to the second LEFT-JOIN that also has the vendor alias available to filter out.

Comment: this is perfect and the most elegant I think out of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it seems you are looking to count how many parts in each category each vendor could have listed as as product but hasn't.
That's basically the difference between how many parts can be listed for each category, and how many were actually listed. 
So you could count the possible and left join to a count of the actual.

Based on the sqlfiddle, the code below also assumes that you want to be able to focus on one season type, and that only parts (with sales?) listed in partdata are relevant.

```
   select c.name as category
      , v.name as vendor
      , cpartcount.parts
      , cpartcount.parts-coalesce(cvpartcount.parts,0) as missingparts
   from vendor v
   cross join
   ( 
     select pt.category_id, count(pt.id) as parts
     from part pt 
     where pt.id in 
     (
       select s.part_id
       from season s 
       where s.type='Type A'
     )
     and pt.id in 
     (
       select pd.part_id
       from part_data pd
     )
     group by pt.category_id
   ) cpartcount
   join category c
   on cpartcount.category_id=c.id
   left join
   ( 
      select pt.category_id, v.id as vendor_id, count(pt.id) as parts
      from part pt,vendor v
      where (v.id,pt.id) IN
      (
        select p.vendor_id, s.part_id
        from product p
        join inventory i
        on p.id=i.product_id
        join season s 
        on i.season_id = s.id
        join part_data pd
        on s.part_id=pd.part_id
        where s.type='Type A'   
      ) 
      group by pt.category_id,v.id
   ) as cvpartcount
   on cpartcount.category_id=cvpartcount.category_id
   and v.id=cvpartcount.vendor_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the 2'nd query has a `GROUP BY` on a field from the sub-query (`vendor`) that is join in `LEFT JOIN` so it will create an output row per each of the vendors (including `NULL` for rows from season that don't have a match with the sub-query).

More specifically - your `count` is on

`COUNT(CASE WHEN in_stock IS NULL THEN pt.id END) AS missing_parts`

(I would prefer writing `SUM(in_stock IS NULL)`)

but since `in_stock` is an aggregation result per each `vendor` - you'll never have a `NULL` value there. ([check the sub-query results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/088e7/55/0))

I think you should clarify the goal of your queries. For example - the first one is returning -

Per each category the number of parts it has on the given seasons, and the **number of seasons that this category wasn't available** (and not the number of missing parts, since there is no join on category with the sub-query).